# How keep a button pressed until the method end

Tags: java, android

I need to keep a button pressed until the method end, because the user not can press again while the button stays pressed.

I tryed this:

on create:

```
Button btnSend= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
btnSend.setOnClickListener(onClickbtnSend);
```

Method:

```
Button.OnClickListener onClickbtnSend= new Button.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
     try{
         v.setPressed(true);

         //do something ......     

     } catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   v.setPressed(false);
}
```

Somebody have idea? Thanks

Comment: Common practice would be to disable/enable the button. I'd suggest looking into that.

Comment: Is the `//do something` a background task? If not then you do not need anything like this. The reason is because the `onClick` will not be called again until the method finishes (as the UI is blocked). This is the default behavior of android. Please clarify what is going wrong now..

Comment: First of all, thanks for helps.. So.. Amulya Khare , It's background task.

Comment: Amulya Khare, I just need that in the moment onClick, the button stays pressed until the method end.

Comment: Please can you post the complete method. Looking at your code, I can proabably help you out much quickly..

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a ToggleButton instead since your button seems to have two states (busy or not).

Comment: Thanks Frank, but this component not apply in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

Before on Create:

```
private boolean pressionado = false;
```

Method:

```
Button.OnClickListener onClickbtnSend= new Button.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v){

    if(pressionado){
      return;
    }

    pressionado = true;

    try{
        //do something background in task

    } catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
        pressionado = false;
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the better solution, but worked for me.